# iOS pushnotification receiving Device Token but not no notification using Phonegap Build

Tags: apple-push-notifications, phonegap-build

I am trying to implement push notification using PhoneGap Build. 
I am receiving a Device Token on my iOS Device but not receiving a Notification in the tray. Here my success call back is getting called but then the callback function is not getting called. 
I have included the latest version of push plugin in config.xml.

Few Points about App:

1. This is my first app
2. I am implementing it using Phonegap Build
3. iOS device : Iphone 6s : iOS 9
4. Android Device: Samsung: Android 4.1.2
5. I am receiving the tray notification using below code in Android (though Android is delayed) but not in my iOS device.

Do Let me know if you need more information.

Here is the javascript code snippet.

```
onDeviceReady: function() { 
//alert('Inside onDeviceReady'); 
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification; 
//var device = window.plugins. 
//alert ('Value of Variable Pushnotification : ' + pushNotification); 
    //alert ('Device Platform : ' + device.platform); 
if (device.platform === 'android' || device.platform === 'Android') 
{ 
//alert('Inside Register Call for Android'); 
pushNotification.register(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler,{"senderID":"935585158292","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"}); 
} 
else 
{ 
//alert('Inside Register Call for iOS'); 
pushNotification.register(app.pg_token_handler, app.pg_error_handler, {"badge": "true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"app.on_pg_apn_notification"}); 
} 
}, 

on_pg_apn_notification: function(event) 
{ 
if ( event.alert ) 
{ 
alert('Inside Alert call of APN Notification'); 
navigator.notification.alert(event.alert); 
} 

if ( event.sound ) 
{ 
alert('Inside sound call of APN Notification'); 
var snd = new Media(event.sound); 
snd.play(); 
} 

if ( event.badge ) 
{ 
alert('Inside Badge call of APN Notification'); 
pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler, event.badge); 
} 
} 

}
```

Pasting Config.xml relevant code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>CalendarSync</name>

    <description>
        This is my first application using PhoneGap
    </description>

    <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
        Aditya Lele
    </author>
    <platform name="ios|winphone|wp8|android" />
    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>
    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
    <preference name="android-build-tool"         value="gradle" /> 
    <!--
        Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app.

    -->
    <preference name="phonegap-version"/>

    <!-- Plugins -->

    <!-- Core plugins -->
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.5.0"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" spec="0.3.0" source="pgb" />

    <!-- Third party plugins -->

    <!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
    <!--
        <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
    -->

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
    <string>100</string>
    </gap:config-file>

    <!--
        Define access to external domains.
        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.
        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->

    <access origin="*"/>
    <!-- Added the following intents to support the removal of whitelist code from base cordova to a plugin -->
    <!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
        <!-- <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" spec="1.0.0" source="npm" />
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>    
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
</feature> -->
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

Comment: cross-post [Nitobi](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/ios-pushnotification-receiving-device-token-but-not-no-notification)

Answer (score 0):

IOS does not show a notification if the app is open, so I'm betting your code is correct.
From Apple Developer documents:

> If your app is already in the foreground, iOS does not show the notification.

Source: [Handling an Actionable Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW27)

I would recommend you write some custom notification like a popup to trigger when the app is open and a notification is received.

Comment: Android on the other hand is able to display the notification when the app is open as you have tested yourself.